# Forcing select2 ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have 2 select2 and when one of them changes the other one loads it's content using the built in select2 ajax function, the problem is that in the case only one element comes from the server I want it to be loaded by default, but for what I have seen the ajax call is only executed when opening the select2 in question. Here is the code I run when the first selec2 is changed in order to change the second's data:

```
$select1.on('change', function () {
    initializeLocationsSelect2($select2, $select1.val(), $template, omId);
});

function initializeLocationsSelect2(tag, s1Value, template, id) {
   tag.val("");
   tag.select2({
        placeholder: "Please Select One",
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        multiple: true,
        tokenSeparators: [","],
        tags: false,
        ajax: {
            url: tag.data('url'),
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                   return {
                        id: id,
                        value: s1Value
                    };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
            }
        },
        formatSelection: function (item) {
            return $.format(template.html(), item.text);
        },
        formatResult: function (item) {
                return $.format(template.html(), item.text);
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
    });
}
```

just in case it is relevant, the second select2 is attached to a `<hidden>` tag

Comment: Can you post the code you used to load the content for the first select (select1)?

Comment: the first select2 (select1) is a select2 attached to a `select` tag, that works just fine if you have any suspicion, could you please tell me